# Where this statement "I know how to control the universe" Mentioned in Bhagvad Gita?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, shloka, reference-request

In which Slok of Bhagvad Gita , Supreame Lord Krishna said that "*I know how to control the universe?*" .

I suspected that he said something different from that but not exactly that Statement but instead I am not sure!

*So Can anyone provide me such refrence of slok  where this similar statement is mentioned in Bhagvad Gita* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there in the Bhagavad Gita there is a verse namely **[Bg. 9.10](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/9/10/)** which states as follows:

> मयाध्यक्षेण प्रकृति: सूयते सचराचरम् । हेतुनानेन कौन्तेय
> जगद्विपरिवर्तते ॥ १० ॥

Translation of this verse is:

> This material nature, which is one of My energies, is working under My
> direction, O son of Kuntī, producing all moving and non-moving beings.
> Under its rule this manifestation is created and annihilated again and
> again.

So you can conclude in a way that Krishna states that he is the controller of everything around here in this universe.